# Android: How to tell whether month comes before day

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

Application: a digital clock. I want to know whether the current date should be displayed as mm.dd.yy or dd.mm.yy for the current locale. Bonus points for identifying yy.mm.dd cases. (I an perfectly content to not support non-Gregorian calendars).

So for example: Should January 31, 2019 be displayed as 01.31.19, or 31.01.19.

Being able to get a short date format string would suffice.  i.e.  "MM/dd/yy", or "yy.MM.dd".

I've rummaged through `DateFormat`, and `SimpleDateFormat` (the latter of which has what I need in the `pattern` private member, but doesn't provide public access). But as usual, date support in Java is infuriatingly... complicated. :-(

Comment: Can you use the new `java.time` package instead?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.